# Image Thumbnail and Title in bottom

Tags: html, css, image, thumbnails

Respectable Gurus
I am running website (https://urdunovelcollection.com/), I just want to convert books thumbnail just like using in gsmarena.com mobile thumbnail, I am not great in styling things, It will be great if someone share some html and css code here, Please help me to resolve my problem.
[image]

Comment: You will have to explain (*in your question description*) what you mean with *...convert books thumbnail just like using in gsmarena.com mobile thumbnail...*. Thumb size? Spacing? Transparency? Hover behavior? Tooltips? And please post a [reprex] , as not many people on SO will switch back and forth between the linked pages trying to figure out what you want.

Comment: I exactly want to convert books thumbnail just like using in gsmarena.com mobile thumbnail. I mean I want the exact look and style as shown in above screenshot. I dont want Borders, Hovers just like above screenshot.